# php send e-mail with PDF attachment

Tags: php, email-attachments, fpdf

I am creating pdf using [FPDF](http://fpdf.org) . Pdf is generating perfectly and also pdf is available with email. But i want to send body message also. I have tried with body message. Example Fine text message `This is text message from shohag` But only pdf attachment is available and body is empty. Here is my code.

```
function send_pdf_to_user(){
    if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'pdf_invoice' ){
        require('html2pdf.php');
        $pdf=new PDF_HTML();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
        $pdf->AddPage();

        $text = get_html_message($_REQUEST['eventid'], $_REQUEST['userid']);
        if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')=='1')
        $text=stripslashes($text);
        $pdf->WriteHTML($text);

        //documentation for Output method here: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm
        $attach_pdf_multipart = chunk_split( base64_encode( $pdf->Output( '', 'S' ) ) );


        //define the receiver of the email 
        $to = 'monirulmask@gmail.com';

        //define the subject of the email 
        $subject = 'Test Invoice'; 
        //create a boundary string. It must be unique 
        //so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
        $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
        //define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
        $headers = "From: webmaster@test.ch\r\nReply-To: webmaster@test.ch"; 
        //add boundary string and mime type specification 
        $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";       



        $msg .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"attachment.pdf\"\r\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n";
        $msg .= $attach_pdf_multipart . "\r\n";

        $msg .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $msg .= "<p>This is text message from shohag</p>\r\n\r\n";  

        global $message;
        $message = '';
        $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $msg, $headers );
        //@mail( $to1, $subject, $msg, $headers );
        if(!empty($mail_sent)):
            $message = "Invoice sent succuessfully";
        else:
            $message = "Error occured. Please try again.";
        endif;
    }
}
```

Please check my code and let me know further possibility. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) with [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) . It works properly without any hassle. You need to change parameter for `$pdf->Output` . Download and copy `class.phpmailer.php` and `PHPMailerAutoload.php` to your work folder. Attach `class.phpmailer.php` below or above `require('html2pdf.php');` . I have done this before so this will work. According to your code this should work.

```
function send_pdf_to_user(){
    if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'pdf_invoice' ){
        require('html2pdf.php');
        require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
        $pdf=new PDF_HTML();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
        $pdf->AddPage();

        $text = get_html_message($_REQUEST['eventid'], $_REQUEST['userid']);
        if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')=='1')
        $text=stripslashes($text);
        $pdf->WriteHTML($text);

        $mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
        $body = "This is test mail by monirul";
       
        $mail->AddReplyTo("webmaster@test.ch","Test Lernt");
        $mail->SetFrom('webmaster@test.ch', 'Test Lernt');
       
        $address = "monirulmask@gmail.com";
        $mail->AddAddress($address, "Abdul Kuddos");       
        $mail->Subject    = "Test Invoice";       
        $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
       
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        //documentation for Output method here: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm       
        $pdf->Output("Test Invoice.pdf","F");
        $path = "Walter Lernt Invoice.pdf";
         
        $mail->AddAttachment($path, '', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
        global $message;
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
          $message =  "Invoice could not be send. Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
          $message = "Invoice sent!";
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working. Thank your effort. Using PHPmailer is good idea.

Answer (score 9):

Use this simple code to send email with pdf attachment. Hope this help you. Thanks.

```
// Settings
$name        = "Name goes here";
$email       = "someome@anadress.com";
$to          = "$name <$email>";
$from        = "Gyan-Shah ";
$subject     = "Here is your attachment";
$mainMessage = "Hi, here's the file.";
$fileatt     = "./test.pdf"; //file location
$fileatttype = "application/pdf";
$fileattname = "newname.pdf"; //name that you want to use to send or you can use the same name
$headers = "From: $from";

// File
$file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
$data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);

// This attaches the file
$semi_rand     = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers      .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
  "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
  $mainMessage  . "\n\n";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
  " name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
  "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
  " filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
 "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

// Send the email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

  echo "The email was sent.";

}
else {

  echo "There was an error sending the mail.";
}
```

Comment: When I try this I don't have a mail content :-(

Comment: This works fantastically, but please replace the reference to `-{$mime_boundary}` with `--{$mime_boundary}` and at the bottom replace `-{$mime_boundary}-` with `--{$mime_boundary}--` as this resolves the issue Maximilian mentioned.

Comment: I had to replace \n with \r\n for it to work

Answer (score 6):

No external libraries are necessary really. Follow this format:

```
$to          = "email1@domain.com, email2@domain.com"; // addresses to email pdf to
$from        = "sent_from@domain.com"; // address message is sent from
$subject     = "Your PDF email subject"; // email subject
$body        = "<p>The PDF is attached.</p>"; // email body
$pdfLocation = "./your-pdf.pdf"; // file location
$pdfName     = "pdf-file.pdf"; // pdf file name recipient will get
$filetype    = "application/pdf"; // type

// create headers and mime boundry
$eol = PHP_EOL;
$semi_rand     = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers       = "From: $from$eol" .
  "MIME-Version: 1.0$eol" .
  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;$eol" .
  " boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"";

// add html message body
  $message = "--$mime_boundary$eol" .
  "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"$eol" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit$eol$eol" .
  $body . $eol;

// fetch pdf
$file = fopen($pdfLocation, 'rb');
$data = fread($file, filesize($pdfLocation));
fclose($file);
$pdf = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

// attach pdf to email
$message .= "--$mime_boundary$eol" .
  "Content-Type: $filetype;$eol" .
  " name=\"$pdfName\"$eol" .
  "Content-Disposition: attachment;$eol" .
  " filename=\"$pdfName\"$eol" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64$eol$eol" .
  $pdf . $eol .
  "--$mime_boundary--";

// Send the email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
  echo "The email was sent.";
}
else {
  echo "There was an error sending the mail.";
}
```

Comment: Today 27 of June 2023. And still perfect answer. Notice that a few other replies don't work with Epson Mail Print with attachement, but the one from omikes work like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

change this:

```
$msg .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"attachment.pdf\"\r\n";
```

To this:

```
$msg = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"attachment.pdf\"\r\n";
```

Comment: If i do this then it won't send any pdf attachment.

Comment: Ah this is interesting.. it could be the solution, I'm waiting for Monirul to test and let us know.. I guess you're suggesting that, if he starts with the $msg. it'd add some random chars at the beginning because it hasn't been declared as null at the start? is that why @Kyle?

Comment: Monirul, only for the first line, you do without the <dot> "."...for the rest of them, you should keep the <dot>

Comment: well you have to concatenate your strings.

Comment: @omar-ali: Its concatenation.  He is "appending" strings to an existing string

Comment: OH come on :) I know it's concatenation.. i just didn't bother writing the whole 'concatenation' word.. :)

Comment: Nop. Its not working. Only PDF is being sent. Not message body. I am trying to send both.

Comment: is your last 3 $msg strings in the email? Because those I believe should be in your headers. Also why the @mail ()?